# Meta-Analysis: Effect size calculation from test statistics (within subject)

Tags: repeated-measures, meta-analysis, effect-size

I am trying to conduct a quantitative meta-analysis on an effect measured within subjects. I am currently facing the issue that I **don't have any means or SD**, but only **F- and t-statistics**, but I'd like to calculate **Cohen's d.**

As [this article (Dunlap 1996)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280844938_Meta-Analysis_of_Experiments_with_Matched_Groups_or_Repeated_Measures_Designs)  points out quite well, there is an issue with the calculation of effect sizes in that case. I also **can't extract a correlation (r)** from the studies I'd like to include. [Lakens (2013)](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fpsyg.2013.00863/full) gives a formula for calculating d in a within subject design, but I was told this is only an estimate for power-analysis but not sufficient for meta-analysis.

Is there any other way than to estimate the correlation as recommended by [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/217763/within-subject-effect-size-when-no-correlation-available)?
Or more general, my question is: what is the **best way to achieve the closest estimate of the effect sizes in a t-test and an F-test with repeated measures, if neither SD, µ nor r are given**.

Thanks a lot to anyone taking the time to read and/or answer this!

Comment: I have deleted my, now redundant, comments

Comment: So to clarify each study gives you a $t$ statistic for the change between pre and post and you know the sample size?

Comment: yes, I either have t- or F- statistics (from repeated meassures ANOVAs) for each study, and also the sample sizes.